# Difference in chi-squared calculated by anova from cph and coxph

Tags: r, regression, anova, chi-squared-test, cox-model

Is there a difference between chi-squared (from `coxph` -> `anova`) and Wald chi-squared (from `cph` -> `anova`)?

And how do I have to interpret these chi-squared values? What does a P<0.05 mean in this case? Why does the sum of chi-squared values of each variable not equal TOTAL? My idea was that each chi-squared indicates the predictive information of each variable and TOTAL that of the entire model.

```
> library(survival)
> library(rms)
>
> data(colon)
> d <- colon
> m1 <- cph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + nodes, data=d)
> anova(m1)
                Wald Statistics          Response: Surv(time, status) 

 Factor     Chi-Square d.f. P     
 age          0.03     1    0.8612
 sex          0.93     1    0.3349
 nodes      189.79     1    <.0001
 TOTAL      192.01     3    <.0001
> 0.03+0.93+189.79 # = 190.75
[1] 190.75
> m2 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + nodes, data=d)
> anova(m2)
Analysis of Deviance Table
 Cox model: response is Surv(time, status)
Terms added sequentially (first to last)

       loglik    Chisq Df Pr(>|Chi|)    
NULL  -6424.0                           
age   -6423.6   0.7147  1     0.3979    
sex   -6423.4   0.5019  1     0.4787    
nodes -6356.9 132.8685  1     <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Answer (score 13):

### Test differences

There are two differences between the two tests used:

1. The use of likelihood ratio tests versus Wald tests
2. The use of a sequential tests versus tests for the effect of one variable given the other variables

Since your example data set is huge (1822 complete observations, with 897 events) the first difference doesn’t matter much, so let’s first look at the second difference.

### Sequential tests versus tests of one variable given the others

Note that the output from running `anova()` on the `coxph` model says `Terms added sequentially (first to last)`. This means that for the first variable, `age`, we simply test if `age` is a statistically significant predictor *without looking at any other variables*. Basically, we test if the model including `age` fits the data better than a model with no explanatory variables (only an intercept), using a likelihood ratio test (which we can do, since the models are nested). This should give the same result as

```
anova(coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age, data=d))
```

(The actual results differ slightly, because of missing data in the other explanatory variables. If you remove the observations with missing data, you will get the *exact* same answer.)

For the second variable, `sex`, we test if `sex` is statistically significant given `age`; we compare a model containing only `age` with one containing *both* `age` and `sex`.

For the third variable, `nodes`, we test if `nodes` is statistically significant given both `age` and `sex`; we compare a model containing both `age` and `sex` with one containing `age`, `sex` *and* `nodes`. This is the only test where we can compare the result to the one from `anova(m1)`.

### Getting tests of one variable given the others for `coxph` models

For getting test results from the `coxph` models comparable to the ones in the `cph` models in general, we have several options. One simple method is to use `drop1()` to compare the full model (three predictors) with ones containing all predictors except one, using likelihood ratio test. First, to avoid some problems with differing number of observations depending on which variables we include, we refit the models on the complete data:

```
d.comp = na.omit(d[c("time","status","age","sex","nodes")])
m2.comp = update(m2, data=d.comp)
```

No we drop each predictor in turn:

```
drop1(m2.comp, test="Chisq")
```

and get

```
       Df   AIC     LRT Pr(>Chi)    
<none>    12720                     
age     1 12718   0.031   0.8611    
sex     1 12719   0.929   0.3351    
nodes   1 12851 132.868   <2e-16 ***
```

As you see, the results are very similar to the ones from the Wald tests from `cph`.

### Wald tests?

So what are the Wald tests? Basically, since all predictors are continuous, they’re just normal, asymptotic *z*-tests, but with squared test statistics. That is, each test statistic is the square of the $z$ statistic from `summary(m2.comp)` (and the $z$ statistic is the estimated coefficient divided by its standard error). Example:

```
summary(m2.comp)

            coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
age    0.0004934  1.0004936  0.0028216  0.175    0.861    
sex   -0.0645554  0.9374842  0.0669405 -0.964    0.335    
nodes  0.0872323  1.0911501  0.0063330 13.774   <2e-16 ***
```

The $z$-statistic of `sex` is $-0.0645554/0.0669405=-0.964$, and $(-0.964)^2=0.93$, which is the chi-square statistic of the Wald test of the `sex` predictor from the `cph` model. (For factors and nonlinear variables, the calculations are slightly more complex, taking the correlation between the estimators of the (dummy/transformed) variables used to represent the factor / nonlinear effect into account.)

### Which tests to use?

Both sequential tests and tests of one variable given the others makes sense, but they test different hypotheses. The former basically ask ‘if I add this new predictor, does it improve the fit?’ iteratively, for an *ordered* list of potential predictors. The latter asks ‘given that I include *all other* predictors, does adding this one improve the fit?’.

### Wald tests versus likelihood ratio tests

The other difference between the two tests, i.e., difference 1 mentioned above, is the difference between asymptotic Wald tests (basically relying on the central limit theorem – that you have enough observations that test statistics are approximately normally distributed) and (partial-)likelihood ratio tests (LRTs). For small data sets, the results can differ somewhat. (And even here, the test statistic for the `nodes` variable is quite different.) Usually, likelihood ratio tests are preferred.

And if you want to compare the Wald and the LRT tests on the same model fitted using ‘coxph()’ (or other normal regression functions), it’s very easy to do using the `car` package:

```
library(car)
Anova(m2.comp, test.statistic="Wald") # Equal to anova(m1)
Anova(m2.comp, test.statistic="LR")   # Equal to drop1(m2.comp, test="Chisq")
```

which gives us:

```
# LR
      LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
age        0.0  1       0.86    
sex        0.9  1       0.34    
nodes    132.9  1     <2e-16 ***

# Wald
            Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
age          1   0.03       0.86    
sex          1   0.93       0.33    
nodes        1 189.73     <2e-16 ***
```

Not surprisingly, the $p$-values are (for any practical use) identical.

Comment: Really? You think `anova.rms` is using so-called "type III" test?

Comment: @Dwin No, as I wrote, `anova.rms` uses *Wald* tests. I wrote ‘type III’-*style* tests, meaning that they basically test the effect of one variable given the others. And that’s what they do here (in this example). In general, they respect the principle of marginality, so I guess it’s closer to ‘type II’ tests. But the terminology of ‘type III/II’ are really for linear models (where they correspond to various types of sums of squares); see Brian Ripley’s ‘Exegeses on Linear Models’: http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/MASS3/Exegeses.pdf

Comment: @Dwin But I agree that the reference to ‘types’ of tests can be more confusing then enlightening, so I have reworded the answer to explictly mention exactly what tests are being done, and removed the reference to ‘type III/II-style tests’. (For models with interactions, things are slightly more complicated, but since this question wasn’t about such models, I think it’s better not confuse matters with more detailed information on what `anova.rms` does in those cases.)

Comment: +1, very helpful,  but I have strata in my results which most anova functions seem to struggle with. `anova.coxph()` can deal with this but operates sequentially, but I want `drop1()` style (I tried `drop1()` and R aborted). Any advice here?